# Ruby unit test assert match case insensitive strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, unit-testing

In a Ruby unit test, how do I assert that a string matches another string even though the casing might be different? I want to avoid sanitizing the two strings to match incase I need to come back and do some investigation but at the same time they are the same outcomes.

```
e.g assert_match 'Test', 'TEST'
```

I've tried fudging with assert_match to make an case insensitive compare but I have had no luck thus far and I cannot get past the old implicit conversion of Regexp into String.

```
module Test::Unit::Assertions
  def assert_match matcher, obj, msg = nil
    msg = message(msg) { "Expected #{mu_pp matcher} to match #{mu_pp obj}" }
    assert_respond_to matcher, :"=~"
    matcher = Regexp.new Regexp.escape matcher if String === matcher
    assert matcher =~ /#{obj}/i, /#{msg}/i
  end
end
```

Comment: while downcase is definitely the easiest for this case you could use `assert_match /Test/i, 'TEST'` [Example](http://rubular.com/r/ncKw2ZIowQ). `assert_match` expects a "matcher" (Regex to match against) and the "obj" the value to try and match. "msg" is simply the message to display on failure. To make this dynamic you could simply use `assert_match /#{matcher}/i, value` where matcher is the string to match and value is the string to compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `downcase` on both of the strings.

```
assert_equal "expected".downcase, actual.downcase
```

or write your own method:

```
def assert_equal_case_insensitive(expected, actual)
  assert_equal expected.downcase, actual.downcase
end
```